# Is there any limit with number of images I can share with UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

Here , Is the code of sharing 10 images on whatsApp Using `UIActivityController`, when i am add 11th images the WhatsApp Icon on `UIActivityController` not display .so is there any limit in `UIActivityController` to Share only 10 or Less than 10 images .if any one share more than 10 images than plz share the code with me..

```
@IBAction func whatsappShareWithImages(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    let image1 = UIImage(named: "a")
    let image2 = UIImage(named: "b")
    let image3 = UIImage(named: "c")
    let image4 = UIImage(named: "d")
    let image5 = UIImage(named: "e")
    let image6 = UIImage(named: "f")
    let image7 = UIImage(named: "g")
    let image8 = UIImage(named: "h")
    let image9 = UIImage(named: "i")
    let image10 = UIImage(named: "k")

    let dataToShare = [image1, image2, image3,image4, image5, image6,image7, image8, image9,image10]

    let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: dataToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

    self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you share through UIActivityViewController or external share, the maximum count & the document type you can share depends on the app to which you are sharing.

As Whatsapp can share max of 10 image at a time through UIActivityViewController so when you select 11th image, Whatsapp icon disappears.

Comment: It seems that there's a limit (memory?) to the number (or size?) you can share through AirDrop (no 3rd App there). I had sharing fail silently from iOS to Mac. The share popup will just close and do nothing, where a smaller number of images will go through.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is 10 Image Limit with Whats App using UIActivityView Controller.

Using Whats app You can share 30 Image with camera role.

Happy Coding :)